# Which spray adhesive should I use to temporarily glue a laminated piece of paper to plastic?

Tags: adhesives

I want to apply laminated piece of paper as an arcade machine video game controller cover but I want to later be able to remove it cleanly from the controller.

[image]

There are a ton of spray adhesives but none of them make it clear if they can be removed. Some say "repositionable" but looking at the instructions that usually just means they don't dry instantly so you have a few minutes window where you can remove them.

Effectively I'm looking for an adhesive that is slightly more adherent than a post-it note. Maybe as adhesive as a vinyl sticker which usually come off cleanly in my experience.

(would also love advice on the paper itself ... in the comments?. Need it to stand up to greasy fingers etc. Was going to laminate but if there is some other method, maybe not paper? Note: the final cover will have a design on it and hence needs to be printed.)

Answer (score 2):

There is such a thing as Post-it Note adhesive sticks, which allow you to "make any paper sheet into a Post-it note".

In my experience it works well, but doesn't come off absolutely cleanly. That said, what little residue there is wipes off easily with a cloth.

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Removable-Restickable-Stick-49oz-Repositionable/dp/B001GXFB4K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GXFB4K)

Comment: Not really sure that this product will work for the use case.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to have the sticker printed at a professional printer to make removable cling-type window stickers. I believe it is usually vinyl and it sticks with static-electricity. Anything homemade is going to suck.

Comment: maybe just printing on a vinyl sticker using an inkjet printer? I know they sell them. I don't know how well the inks will stand up to being touched. [Though maybe I could spray some kind of coating/ sealant over it after printing](https://www.onlinelabels.com/articles/krylon-weatherproof-waterproof-label-overcoat-spray.htm)

Comment: @gman they won’t stand up to that kind of use. You could double them though, in that you have one print layer and one layer on top of that. I wouldn’t use spray sealant.